# Promoted by app to production but still says (Beta)

Tags: android, google-play, beta

I was running an app in the Google Play in Beta and then just recently "released to production" using a higher version APK.

However when I go to Google Play listing my app still says AppName (Beta)? I thought it just needed some time to propagate but I made the change 2 days ago and its still showing like that.

Anyone know how to correct this?

Comment: can you post play store console screenshots

Comment: did you find a solution or how much I have to wait?

Comment: Just clear all the cookies on the play store site. It worked for me. Hope it will help others facing the situation

Answer (score 44, accepted):

It actually looks like its some kind of caching issue or user specific issue.
I decided to open Google Play store from a different browser (where I was not logged in) and the app was no longer showing as Beta.
Only when viewing Play store from my logged in account and from my phone is it showing (BETA).

So for any non-beta testers viewing it for the first time on their phone or via browser I assume its going to show up correctly, which is good enough for me.

Comment: Well I'm still experiencing this bug. App is promoted to production, but on the dev's account it still shows "(Beta)" mark which causes confusion (From other accounts show correctly without "(Beta)".

Comment: It's due to being a beta tester.

Comment: I find this unsatisfactory and annoying, but a workaround is to leave beta testing. If you go to the play store app and scroll down, it says "you are a beta tester" and has a button that gives the option to "Leave". You can do this and instruct your beta testers to do this and they will see production and be able to write reviews.

Comment: @Brent you don't get it, captain, if beta version is older than release then it should show release version not beta

Comment: clearing google play store's cache (settings -> apps -> view all -> google play) is the only thing that got rid of all the problems related to this issue for me.

Comment: Clearing the cache works for me! Thanks @BradenHolt

Comment: Adding to @AlanTodtenkopf comment, opening listing, scrolling and finding option to Leave may be difficult for users so one can ask users to open https://play.google.com/apps/testing/com.example.your_package URL and leave the program.

Answer (score 15):

It seems that this is from the user's account side. If one specific account subscribed to a beta program it will show as (BETA) on the Google Play Store.
So to remove the beta the user just has to do the following:

- Open the Google Play Store on the device.
- Find the app he wants to leave.
- Tap the app to open the detail page for the app.
- Scroll down to find the section on beta testing.
- Tap Leave.

Note: I Didn't find out a way to remove this on the Play Console but google i think they should have an option to do it.

Answer (score 9):

I face the same issues . I have published my app two days before but it still showing that App Name(Beta). This happens due to only if you are the  beta tester of that app .When you see it from another browser or other google play store ,It won't show beta.But keep in mind that you aren't a member of tester for this app.
 To resolve this problem do these things:-

1. Please remove your account as beta tester from that app.
2. Or, Log out from device.Again login google account in your device .

   3) Clear cache of Google Play Store.

Perhaps ,this will help you. Thanks..

Answer (score 5):

It is due to Play Store caching , clear data of the Play Store , you will no longer see it as beta, plus make sure you are trying to see app on play store from a non-beta account.

Comment: Yes ,That is the main reason

Answer (score 4):

It's simple l, just delete the tester list from testers in internal testing console, then clear cache from playstore, your good to go.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem and it turned out to simply be that I was logged in to google with an account that had signed up as a beta tester.  I logged out of google and then the page displayed correctly.  So it seems to me the (beta) is related to your account and not the software release which is sub-optimal coding on the part of google.

Answer (score 3):

It showing AppName(Beta) just because of you are a Beta tester for that app.
There are two options:

1. Logout from browser and then check(different user that should not be a tester)
2. copy URL and open in in different browser

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to clear storage of play store application on my device.

Somehow I could not update, my test track was paused, there was no way to opt out so out of desperate I just cleared storage of play store app and done, everything back in normal.  PS: Yeah I also deleted app and reinstalled before that maybe this was not necessary, don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Although @Ruben Miquelino's answer is correct, it is not practical to ask every user (users already on beta) to go to a link and remove beta.

I have found a better solution for this problem, If we deactivate the beta track and change target countries(only for beta) then those users will automatically be moved to Production (after Google's review process & Play store cache expiry)

Answer (score 0):

For those who are still looking for a solution, you can clear the Goole Play Store cache by following the steps mentioned by Google [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/9037938?hl=en):

> **Clear the cache & data of the Play Store**
>
> This gives the app a fresh start and can help fix issues.
>
> 1. On your Android phone or tablet, open the Settings app Settings.
> 2. Tap Apps & notifications and then See all apps.
> 3. Scroll down and tap Google Play Store Google Play.
> 4. Tap Storage and then Clear Cache.
> 5. Tap Clear data.
> 6. Re-open the Play Store, and try your download again.